# git - Remove master files and folders from gh-pages

Tags: git, github

I've setup a `Github` repo where I've committed some code to the `master` branch. I then created a page with `Github`'s own page creator, which generated a new branch alongside the `master` branch called `gh-pages`. I've pushed lots of commits to both branches by now.

The issue I have is that when I switch from `master` to `gh-pages` I can see files and folders from `master` that shouldn't be showing (I think) in the `gh-pages` branch.

I've read [here](http://datadesk.latimes.com/posts/2012/01/sphinx-on-github/) that to stop that from happening the following commands should be used within the `gh-pages` branch:

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/gh-pages
rm .git/index
git clean -fdx
```

I'm not sure what those commands do so I don't want to use them until I'm sure they won't screw up neither branch and that they actually will fix the issue I have with files and folders from `master` showing in `gh-pages`.

Could you explain what these commands do and whether they are suited to fix the issue mentioned above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are telling that HEAD refs/heads/gh-pages is your current working branch by creating a symlink called HEAD with the refs/heads/gh-pages value

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/gh-pages
```

then you are removing the index file of git

```
rm .git/index
```

finally you are cleaning your untracked files

```
git clean -fdx
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @TooShyToAsk, one question: will this stop files and folders from `master` from appearing when I switch to the `gh-pages` branch?

Comment: IDK how/why, but this removed _all_ files in my gh-pages branch and I had to do a `git reset HEAD {file}` and `git checkout -- {file}` to keep the files I wanted after executing these commands and BEFORE committing the changes ;)